What should be the key name when sending a request to an Azure OpenAI endpoint
I have created a phi-3-vision-128K-instruct deployment in Azure AI Studio. I want to send a request to the endpoint using Postman. I need to provide a key. I know the key but I don't know what the header name should be.


Sure, I found the answer in a code snippet, I'll include it here:
requestHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey)

So in PostMan:
Header Name: Authorization
Header Value: Bearer <your-api-key>
